# Database is locked : when reading Chrome history

Tags: c#, sqlite

Whenever I used to capture the browser history I got Database is locked error. while the dataadapter data is fill to dataset this error occurs(i.e.,sd.Fill(ds, "urls");)

error occurs in this line:

```
string google = 
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + 
   @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History";
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(
   "Data Source=" + google + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
connection.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter sd = new SQLiteDataAdapter(
    "select url,title,visit_count,last_visit_time from urls order by last_visit_time",
    connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sd.Fill(ds, "urls");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
connection.Close();
```

Comment: so probably the Chrome browser is running and it has opened the history database in exclusive mode (since SQLite is not a multi user SQL server)

Comment: Yes ji....you are right...After closing my browser this code works well....But I am using the timer I need to capture the history of the user every 1 hour once.....

Comment: without closing the browser....Please give some idea ji